# TV show where a man and a woman go time travelling

Tags: story-identification

TV show about a woman who finds a man and they go on time travel adventures or the like. They go in something; I think it was a telephone box.

Comment: This isn't a lot of detail to go on. Is there anything else you remember about this series?

Comment: @F1Krazy yes I rmember they go in something I think it was a telephone box

Comment: Bill and Ted also used a phone box

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"A man and a woman going on time-travelling adventures in a telephone box" can only be one series: *Doctor Who*. Since the Doctor's appearance and their companion's identity change from series to series, and I have no idea which incarnation you may have watched, posting a picture of them probably isn't going to help jog your memory. So here's a picture of the telephone box, which is actually a disguised alien spaceship called the TARDIS:

[image]

Comment: thanks for that